# Using res.locals.user to show user object in all frontend views

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use `res.locals.user` to show the `user` object in the frontend.

Below you can see in my main `app.js` file the middleware I have created:

```
...    
const passport = require('passport')

const auth = require('./routes/auth')
const index = require('./routes/index')

const app = express()

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.use(logger(process.env.LOG_ENV))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false,
}))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../public')))
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use(session({
  secret: 'super-mega-hyper-secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use((req, res, next) => { //This middleware checks the local user
  res.locals.user = req.user
  next()
})
...
```

My passport file looks like the following:

```
const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const serviceAuth = require('../service/auth')

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser(async(id, done) => {
  const user = await serviceAuth.findById(id)
  done(null, user)
})

// Sign in with username and Password
passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'username',
}, async(username, password, done) => {
  const user = await serviceAuth.signin(username, password)
  done(null, user)
}))


/**
 * Login Required middleware.
 */
exports.isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.locals.user = req.session.user
    return next()
  }
  res.redirect('/')
}
```

However, I get the following error, when trying to display in my pug view the `user` object:

```
TypeError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/src/views/includes/_sidebar.pug:6
    4|          .user-panel
    5|                  .pull-left.info
  > 6|                          p= user.name
    7|                          p= user.role
    8| 
    9|          // Sidebar Menu

Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Any suggestions why the user object is not available in the views AFTER I have properly logged in a user?

Comment: Kindly verify field name which have used  in template, passport staratergy.

Comment: @Dipakchavda Thx for your reply! Basically I am expecting to get the user object in the frontend. Or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT[1]**
You will need 2 entry views in your app:

1. A `index` for the case a user is authenticated
2. A `loginPage` for the case user is not authenticated

You can also handle these both cases in the main view(`index`) but you need to show/hide elements based on the presence of the `currentUser`. But i find having separate views more clean.

Step 1 - add your authentication middleware:

```
const isAuthenticated = require('./path/to/isAuthenticated');
app.use(isAuthenticated)
```

Step 2 - render your app root `/` (**is very important to do this after you registered the auth middleware so that your `res.locals.user` is populated**):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    if(res.locals && res.locals.user){
        res.render('index', { currentUser: res.locals.user });
    } else {
        res.render('loginPage');
    }            
});
```

Step 3 - Add the injected user to the `window` in `index.pug`:

```
if !!currentUser
    script.
        window.currentUser = !{currentUser}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Within my `passport.js` and my `app.js` I am using: `exports.isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.locals.user = req.session.user
    return next()
  }
  res.redirect('/')
}` to set the `res.locals.user` variable. Any suggestions how to make the user object permanently available in the view?

Answer (score 1):

In your `isAuthenticated` function, the `req.session.user` is `undefined`
`Passport.js` store `user` object in `req.use` for each authenticated route, session only store userId.

Your `middleware` in `app.js` file is OK, but the `isAuthenticated` overwrite  `res.locals.user` to `undefined`.

In my opinion you need remove the `middleware` (because it use in all routes) and change `isAuthenticated` like this:

```
exports.isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.locals.user = req.user
    return next()
  }
  res.redirect('/')
}
```