# Global variable for GET all routes METHOD is not working in nodejs after sign in

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've made a blog page with a sign up and sign in.
So I had used the `req.locals.<name>` method

With the GET method.


Code in server.js

```
app.get('*',(req,res, next) => {
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
})
```

And I used the `user` variable in a pug page's navbar like :-

```
nav.navbar.navbar-expand-lg.navbar-light.bg-light
  .container
    a.navbar-brand.text-center.me-2(href='/') IA INFO
    button.navbar-toggler(type='button' data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='#navbarSupportedContent' aria-controls='navbarSupportedContent' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation')
      span.navbar-toggler-icon
    #navbarSupportedContent.collapse.navbar-collapse.justify-content-end
      ul.nav.nav-tabs
        li.nav-item
          a.nav-link(aria-current='page' href='/') Home
        li.nav-item
          a.nav-link(href='/blogs') Blogs
        if user
            li.nav-item
                a.nav-link(href='/blogs/add/new-blog') New Blog
            li.nav-item
                a.nav-link(href='/blogs/admin/sign') Sign
            li.nav-item
                a.nav-link(href='/logout') Logout
```

But when i try this method it doesn't really work....
After anyone logs-in, it is supposed to work but then it shows me an error of user is not defined or it just doesnt work...

Comment: Probably this might help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47265751/using-res-locals-user-to-show-user-object-in-all-frontend-views

Comment: @chandresh_n thank you for helping me out... i tried them but didnt really get it..

Comment: @chandresh_n I did exactly as you mentioned, but this time it shows `Cannot read property 'isSignedIn' of undefined` 
also sorry Im new to this get all route method so im pretty bad...  
Thank you for helping me out!!.  You can check this out for more reference https://github.com/Meheer17/Aarush-blog.git

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting user as null, try setting a boolean inside the user object, more so like:

```
app.get('*',(req,res, next) => {
  res.locals.user = req.user ? {...req.user,...{isSignedIn : true} : {isSignedIn : false}; //spread operator has shortcomings, please use it with care 
  next();
})
```

and then in the pug file:

```
nav.navbar.navbar-expand-lg.navbar-light.bg-light
  .container
    a.navbar-brand.text-center.me-2(href='/') IA INFO
    button.navbar-toggler(type='button' data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='#navbarSupportedContent' aria-controls='navbarSupportedContent' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation')
      span.navbar-toggler-icon
    #navbarSupportedContent.collapse.navbar-collapse.justify-content-end
      ul.nav.nav-tabs
        li.nav-item
          a.nav-link(aria-current='page' href='/') Home
        li.nav-item
          a.nav-link(href='/blogs') Blogs
        if user.isSignedIn //check for the boolean
            li.nav-item
                a.nav-link(href='/blogs/add/new-blog') New Blog
            li.nav-item
                a.nav-link(href='/blogs/admin/sign') Sign
            li.nav-item
                a.nav-link(href='/logout') Logout
```

[Read more about spread operators here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)